# Extract date part from timestamptz

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract the hour from a timestamp with a timezone. However, my times are coming up incorrectly.

Here's an example, I am using Dbeaver with my timezone set to EST:

```
SELECT '2020-01-24 14:27:12' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' as foo,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM foo) as ex,
DATE_PART('HOUR', foo::timestamp) as dp
```

RETURNS:

```
foo                 |ex |dp
2020-01-24 17:27:12 |22 | 22
```

- Why is my time coming up 3 hours ahead, it should be 3 hours behind?
- `Extract` and `DATE_PART` don't seem to get me the hour I would like. It looks like it's taking 17 as EST and then converting it to UTC. Here's what I am expecting to get:

```
foo                 |ex |dp
2020-01-24 11:27:12 |11 | 11
```

Comment: Hi @Jacky, please see this link and comment. Thanks! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=00f581a0df66be1bce80a39793d18586

Comment: Also, please can you show us your full code ? Or this is your full code ??

Comment: My full code is creating the same result as shown. I also tried this on RStudio and got the same results. My database is an Amazon Redshift server.

Comment: Hi @Jacky, check the link again...I have edited it right away but you have clicked on it very fast :) In your question the PostgreSQL is also tagged ?

Comment: And on PostgreSQL all is ok: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8e0582f590ad45bbb502633a58b4fc0f ... Please remove your tag if it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag as the query is a syntax error on Postgres. The aliased `foo` column cannot be referred to.

Comment: I'd be curious what result you get from [this similar query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d4a72da79151af1b50f616fdc641dfe2).

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the postgres link has no problems... This may possibly be an issue with redshift

Comment: @Schwern I got the same incorrect result when I ran your query. This is quite strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your timezone is set to EST:

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');
```

or with:

```
show timezone;
```

If it is not you can set it like this:

```
set timezone to est;
```

AS shown in this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8d5b7191310c9e57a1969f282a901020)

If that is not working try with `convert_timezone`

```
select convert_timezone('US/Pacific', '2020-01-24 14:27:12')
```

And exploring the mater on hand I have found this fact:

> Note Amazon Redshift doesn't validate POSIX-style time zone
>   specifications, so it is possible to set the time zone to an invalid
>   value. For example, the following command doesn't return an error,
>   even though it sets the time zone to an invalid value.
>
> set timezone to ‘xxx36’;

from this source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html

Comment: Show timezone reveals that the db is in UTC but using the query in the example, 17:27:12 as foo and 22 in datepart/extract  is still completely incorrect. It should have been 06:27:12 and 6 respectively. I'm not sure what is causing this issue to occur but your note can possibly be a reason. I did try `America/Los_Angeles` and that yield the same incorrect result. 

However, this did work:
`WITH foo as(
select convert_timezone('US/Eastern','US/Pacific', '2020-01-24 14:27:12') as foo)
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM foo) as ex,
DATE_PART('HOUR', foo::timestamp) as dp
FROM foo;`

Comment: So my answer is helpful and I believe correct because I could of not know what timezone is set but I did lead you to the correct direction. I just want to say you can give up vote for the answers that are helpful and accept answers that are correct... Happy to help, cheers!

Comment: Thanks! For future people reading this: TL;DR: use `convert_timezone` and DO NOT use `AT TIME ZONE x`  on Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

'AT TIME ZONE' does not work like you are expecting. Use convert_timezone() instead.

```
SELECT
  '2020-01-24 14:27:12' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' as foo,  
    -- expected '2020-01-24 6:27:12' got '2020-01-24 22:27:12+00'
  convert_timezone('UTC', 'US/Pacific', CAST('2020-01-24 14:27:12' AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)) as bar 
    -- expected '2020-01-24 6:27:12' got '2020-01-24 06:27:12'
  ;
```

'AT TIME ZONE' interprets the timestamp as being relative to the specified time zone and converts it to a TIMESTAMPTZ offset to UTC. That is in the above example it converts from US/Pacific to UTC, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

It works perfectly fine for me (using dbVisualizer).

The issue is with your SQL Client.

SQL clients often impose formatting that impacts the values you see. You can test this by converting values to Text before sending them to your SQL client:

```sql
SELECT
  '2020-01-24 14:27:12' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' as foo,
  foo::text as t,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM foo) as ex,
  DATE_PART('HOUR', foo::timestamp) as dp
```

For me, this results in:

```
2020-01-24 22:27:12+00  2020-01-24 22:27:12+00  22.0    22.0
```

Try it in your SQL client and see what happens.

Comment: John, I got the same result you showed and my timezone is set to UTC. However, hour 22 is incorrect. It should be at hour 6.  There seems to be a bug when converting timezones in a select statement `AT TIME ZONE x`