# Extracting local date from TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: postgresql

I have read [Extract date part from timestamptz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902758/extract-date-part-from-timestamptz) but this does not answer the question.

I have a `timestamp with time zone` column. Not all values are stored with the same time zone (though I am aware under the hood, postgres is storing them all in UTC).

I would like the extract the date, **in the local time zone.** Not the date after converting it to the database's default timezone, nor after converting it to my session's timezone.

For example, consider `2020-01-01 23:00:00-07`. All three of the below queries return `2020-01-02`, when I the result I want is `2020-01-01`.

```sql
SET TIMEZONE TO 'UTC';

SELECT '2020-01-01 23:00:00-07'::TIMESTAMPTZ::DATE;
SELECT date('2020-01-01 23:00:00-07'::TIMESTAMPTZ);
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', '2020-01-01 23:00:00-07'::TIMESTAMPTZ)::DATE;
```

Changing the time zone of my session to get the desired result is not a solution. I'm looking for a general solution, which should work independently of the session's timezone and work for all offsets which may be stored in the column, not just the one in the above toy example.

Comment: There are no offsets stored in the field data, all values in `timestamptz` are stored as `UTC`.

Comment: The date you want is tied to a time zone, you will need to stipulate what time zone you are interested  when converting to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized shortly after posting this how confused I was. Like Adrian's comment says, the timezone is not really stored. I would have noticed if I just did this

```sql
SELECT '2020-01-01 23:00:00-07'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

So the short answer to my question is that it isn't possible (unless you were storing this information yourself separately).

Instead of deleting this question, I'll leave it up in case any other lost and confused souls have the same question as me, and I'll link to this excellent article which explains this in greater detail https://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/